# Can't access response outside of StringRequest in volley

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I've used [this](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple) simple get request code

```
final StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(removeThisIfItDidntWork);
        String url ="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1";

// Request a string response from the provided URL.
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        result.append(response);
                        System.out.println(result.toString()); //this get the actual result
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

// Add the request to the RequestQueue.
        queue.add(stringRequest);
        System.out.println(result.toString()); //this result an empty string
```

when I print it inside on response it outputs the expected result but when I use it outside it prints an empty string

Comment: You need to implement callback on receiving response. It’s a game of asynchronous.

Comment: @VVB but how to implement that?

Answer (score 0):

`queue.add` adds the request to the queue to be executed at some later time. Immediately after that `result.toString` is called, which is, of course, empty (it was just created empty above, request has not been executed yet).

Later on, request is picked from the queue, executed, and a response is received. Then `onResponse` is called, which adds `response` to the `result`, and prints it out.

Welcome to the world of multi-threading :)

Comment: so, where to go from here? :) any recommendations will be really appreciated. i read the above [create a simple get request in android developer](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple) but they didn't seem to mention how to deal with that outside of my function because the returned value will be an empty string too